Sci-fi story whose moral is to use the tools/weapons you have at your disposal
I am looking for the title of a science-fiction story where it starts off as an officer is talking to a court and describing the events of a space war. The officer recounts that the fleet had sufficient weapons, but a researcher kept telling the officer's superiors about new weapons that were almost ready.
Time passed and the enemy gained more footholds, and the fleet was told not to engage because the researcher kept telling them of even better weapons being developed. This kept on going until the officer's side lost the war, and it turns out that, at the end of the story, the officer is addressing the court and telling them why he couldn't be locked in the same cell as that researcher.
If I recall correctly, a blurb before the story said that it was required reading at the US Naval Academy, with the moral of "use the tools/weapons you have at hand rather than wait for those of tomorrow."

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] more details into your question, e.g. "I know that it isn't Military Inferiority Complex because the fight was in a stellar coral reef, not the asteroids of space, and the enemy side were all under two feet tall".

This question is similar to: Process management and high technology weapon. Novel name and author?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Pete we do not close story id questions as duplicates unless both questions have an answer that has been accepted.

In reality one would use a mixed strategy of exploitation and exploration so that new stuff (that one can actually produce, naturally) can de developed, tested and put online, in time. This is how the USA threw new things into WWII while fighting was going on, among other the radar-controlled AA gun. Recommending the excellent Between Human and Machine: Feedback, Control, and Computing before Cybernetics by David Mindell.

One may also admire the description of the tactical computer in that story: "The Analyzer contained just short of a million vacuum tubes and needed a team of five hundred technicians to maintain and operate it. It was quite impossible to accommodate the extra staff aboard a battleship.." In 1951, when the story was written, the UNIVAC (small Excel sheet in a room) "used 6,103 vacuum tubes, weighed 7.6 t, consumed 125 kW, and could perform about 1,905 operations per second running on a 2.25 MHz clock."

This is "Superiority" by Arthur C. Clarke.
Quoting from the Wikipedia page:

The first of these is repeatedly delayed, and the allies pause their attacks while they wait for their ships to be fitted with the new missiles. The enemy uses these delays to capture several former allied systems. Instead of simply counterattacking with their current weapons, Norden develops still newer weapons that will make up for these losses. Each is temporarily successful, but each invariably leads to insurmountable problems and further losses.

Wikipedia notes:

The story was at one point required reading for an industrial design course at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology.


If so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/857/process-management-and-high-technology-weapon-novel-name-and-author

@FuzzyBoots And so many others too! :D  (But I take your point that is the root.  Probably the oldest question here I've duped against.)
